# masking UIView based on CGRect

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Look at the image please : 
[image]

I have UIView and CGRect. I have to check where CGRect overlays UIView and then set the mask on the area which is "opposed" to intersection. So it's blue part in the image. How to achieve that? 
I know there's CGContextClipToMask but I have no idea how to use that - could someone help me with example code? Is CGContextClipToMask good direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign mask layer to your UIView's layer.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
// Construct path and set it.
[maskLayer setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);

[maskLayer release];
```

Documentation: [CALayer reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But do you have any idea how to "count" this path? It seems that I have to consider all cases (14) and set point by point every time...

Comment: and should I set fillColor to maskLayer ( path? ) ? Because I have lines through points but it's not working... big thanks, Evgeniy!

Comment: Do you want to hide intersection area or to show just it? If you want to hide it, just place opaque view above your blue view. If you want to show it, then my code works fine for that purpose. Set fill color to something opaque and backgroundColor to 100% transparent. You can calculate intersection using the `CGRectIntersection` function.

Comment: Yeah, but yellow is a uiwebview and red one is a popup from yellow. so the proper solution was to set mask on yellow and a intersection and bring blue one to background.