# Simply mask a UIView with a rectangle

Tags: ios, uiview, mask

I want to know how to simply mask the visible area of a UIView of any kind. All the answers/tutorials I've read so far describe masking with an image, gradient or creating round corners which is way more advanced than what I am after.

Example: I have a UIView with the bounds (0, 0, 100, 100) and I want to cut away the right half of the view using a mask. Therefore my mask frame would be (0, 0, 50, 100).

Any idea how to do this simply? I don't want to override the drawrect method since this should be applicable to any UIView.

I've tried this but it just makes the whole view invisible.

```
CGRect mask = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);
UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mask];
viewToMask.layer.mask = maskView.layer;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but why don't you just change the frame of your view to mask? Eg viewToMask.frame = mask; (or the inverse if that's what you want to show.)

Comment: That won't work since the views may have stretchable images which should be cut off, or controls which should still be usable even if masked out. Changing the frame would change the image stretch or make the controls unusable.

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241966/masking-uiview-based-on-cgrect

Comment: It helped :) Adding the way I went with as an answer.

Comment: or this one, mask view by view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805444/masking-a-uiview

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Thanks to the link from MSK, this is the way I went with which works well:

```
// Create a mask layer and the frame to determine what will be visible in the view.
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);

// Create a path with the rectangle in it.
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);

// Set the path to the mask layer.
maskLayer.path = path;

// Release the path since it's not covered by ARC.
CGPathRelease(path);

// Set the mask of the view.
viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: This answer provides a good way to do an inverse mask w/UIBezierPath (though using a circle in the example) -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/15377207/437492

Answer (score 28):

Thanks for answers guys.

In case someone can't find suitable answer on SO for this question for hours, like i just did, i've assembled a working gist in Swift 2.2 for `masking`/`clipping` `UIView` with `CGRect`/`UIBezierPath`:

https://gist.github.com/Flar49/7e977e81f1d2827f5fcd5c6c6a3c3d94

```
extension UIView {

    func mask(withRect rect: CGRect, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        if inverse {
            path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds))
            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        }

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    func mask(withPath path: UIBezierPath, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let path = path
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        if inverse {
            path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds))
            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        }

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let viewSize = targetView.bounds.size
let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: viewSize.width - 20*2, height: viewSize.height - 20*2)

// Cuts rectangle inside view, leaving 20pt borders around
targetView.mask(withRect: rect, inverse: true)

// Cuts 20pt borders around the view, keeping part inside rect intact
targetView.mask(withRect: rect)
```

Hope it will save someone some time in the future :)

Comment: After hours of searching I found you, my savior. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 22):

No need any mask at all.
Just **put it into a wrapper view** with the smaller frame, and set [clipsToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds).

```
wrapper.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Doesn't really work if you want to cut a control, since it won't respond to touches outside its parents frame. Also, this basically does the same thing as setting a mask, except that now you have a relative frame to worry about.

Comment: I think it is more performant, as this one probably adjusts texture coordinates only under the hood, but apply mask probably does alpha blending.

Comment: You can always override -pointInside: to get responses outside the frame. Though, it may be really an overhead for this.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple example in a Swift ViewController, based on the accepted answer:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let redView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(redView)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        mask(redView, maskRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    }

    func mask(_ viewToMask: UIView, maskRect: CGRect) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGPath(rect: maskRect, transform: nil)
        maskLayer.path = path

        // Set the mask of the view.
        viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> An optional layer whose **alpha channel** is used as a mask to select
>   between the layer's background and the result of compositing the
>   layer's contents with its filtered background.
>
> @property(retain) CALayer *mask

The correct way to do what you want is to create the `maskView` of the same frame (0, 0, 100, 100) as the `viewToMask`  which layer you want to mask. Then you need to set the clearColor for the path you want to make invisible (this will block the view interaction over the path so be careful with the view hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I found a simpler way which doesn't use alpha though, so I added my own answer.

Comment: @Accatyyc Nice solution, i've edited it by renaming `maskLayer` and `maskRect` to `homeTeamMaskLayer` and `homeTeamMaskRect` so that it compiles :) Need to wait it to be approved though and thanks for update.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit suggestion. I updated it the other way around though so it makes sense for other projects than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** , thanks @Dan Rosenstark

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let red = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(red)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        red.mask(CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    }
}

extension UIView{
    func mask(_ rect: CGRect){
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)
        mask.path = path
        // Set the mask of the view.
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Setting `MaskToBounds` is not enough, for example, in scenario where you have `UIImageView` that is positioned inside `RelativeLayout`. In case that you put your `UIImageView` to be near top edge of the layout and then you rotate your `UIImageView`, it will go over layout and it won't be cropped. If you set that flag to true, it will be cropped yes, but it will also be cropped if `UIImageView` is on the center of layout, and that is not what you want.

So, determinating `maskRect` is the right approach.